# Iterating through a list of Items in a python list which has the range

Tags: python

I have a list something like this which has a range inside:

I want to get it as a comma separate value with the range expanded.

While i try to iterate through the items of the list using forloop, I dont get the desired result.

```
a = ['1','2','3-10','15-20']
b = []
for item in a:
    if '-' in item:
        print('The value of item is :' , item)
        start = item.split('-')[0]
        print('The value of start is :' , start)
        end = item.split('-')[1]
        print('The value of end is :' , end)
        for i in range(int(start),int(end)):
            b.append(i)
    else:
        b.append(item)

print('The value of b is : ', b)
```

range doesn't include the last element. any better way to handle this?

Comment: Range excludes the last item. If you add ‘+1 ‘ to your end, it should take your entire range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested list comprehensions:

```
a = ['1','2','3-10','15-20']

expanded = [list(range(int(i.split('-')[0]), int(i.split('-')[1])+1)) if '-' in i else [int(i)] for i in a]

flatten = ','.join(map(str, [i for sublist in expanded for i in sublist]))
```

Returns:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: why list(range()) ? range results list of values by default ryt? i've made little changes to your list comprehension:- print reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[range(int(r.split('-')[0]),int(r.split('-')[1])+1) if '-' in r else [int(r)] for r in a])

Comment: `range()` returns a range object, not a `list`

Comment: oops! i didn't check python 3,i'm using python 2 Good Day ji ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add +1 in end as range exclude the last number

```
a = ['1','2','3-10','15-20']
b = []
for item in a:
    if '-' in item:
        print('The value of item is :' , item)
        start = item.split('-')[0]
        print('The value of start is :' , start)
        end = item.split('-')[1]
        print('The value of end is :' , end)
        for i in range(int(start),int(end)+1):
            b.append(i)
    else:
        b.append(item)

print('The value of b is : ', b)
```

Please accept and tick if it solves your problem ;)